# Xamarin Studio C8 Stable iOS simulator custom linker issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin-studio, fips

We're working with Blackberry Dynamics SDK which requires the use of a custom linker to meet FIPS compliance. It can be achieved by passing mtouch arguments gcc_flags="-B {path.to.custom.ld}".

This works for device build but not for simulators. Custom ld points to the BB SDK ld choosing target architecture. For device build there is output from the ld script but for simulator no entries can be found. Compiled and linked executable seems to have been linked by the standard system linker.

When switching to C9 Beta/Alpha channel it works without issues for both device and simulator builds. So this was hopefully covered by one of the bug fixes.

Do you know what is the cause of the issue? Which of the bug fixes resolved this and if this fix will be available on the next stable channel?

Comment: The C9 Beta/Alpha will eventually become the stable version.

Comment: Is this a known issue or something new?

So **ALL** features and bug fixes will eventually land into stable release?

Comment: I do not know if this is a known issue or not, but it would seem that something that was changed in beta alpha resolved this, so there is not much point in filing a bug report as the issue is resolved in the Alpha/Beta. And yes, the idea would be for all bug fixes and features to eventually be released to Stable.